# Is there a way to get the app_config for the current app?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to get an Django app_config instance for the current app.

For example:

**baseapp/views.py**

```
class MyBaseView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        # That's the hypothetical method I would like to have
        app_config = apps.get_current_app_config()

        return app_config.url
```

**app1/views.py**

```
class MyView1(MyBaseView):
    pass
```

**app1/apps.py**

```
class MyApp1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp1'
    verbose_name = 'My Application 1'
    url = 'http://example.com/'
```

**app2/views.py**

```
class MyView2(MyBaseView):
    pass
```

**app2/apps.py**

```
class MyApp2Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp2'
    verbose_name = 'My Application 2'
    url = 'http://example.org/'
```

Basically I want to have a super class able to use sub class information to perform some action. The redirect is just an example because I'm actually doing more complex stuff and reading more data from the sub-classes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeap, the documentation is clear about using the name of the app to get its app_config. What about if I want to know the name of the class I'm currently in?

Answer (score 4):

I've just had to do something similar and the following works;

```
from .apps import MyApp1Config
from django.apps import apps 

app_config = apps.get_app_config(MyApp1Config.name)
```